# C# : How to capture events asynchronously and return a value from a function synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous, polling

This is a C# question
I want to do a synchronous call for asynchronous event call backs.
See comment in code for the req

```
class User
{
    EventHandler Service1Started()
    {
      "Looks like service 1 started as I got event from server class" ;
    }
    EventHandler Service2Started()
    {
      "Looks like service 2 started as I got event from server class" ;
    }
    public void StartServicesOnlyStartService2AfterService1Started()
    {
        Server server = new Server();

         // want to call these 2 methods synchronously here
        // how to wait till service1 has started thru the event we get
        // Want to avoid polling, sleeping etc if possible

        server.StartService1();              
        server.StartService2();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is pretty unclear, but the simplest approach would just be to make the event handler for Service1 start service 2:

```
server.Service1Started += delegate { server.StartService2(); };
```

Comment: I changed question.
The need is to synchronously call two methods
without using polling etc

Comment: @john appleseed: Your question was fairly unclear before - it's even less clear now. What *exactly* do you mean by "synchronously" in this case? You need to make your question a lot clearer. Your methods `Service1Started` and `Service2Started` have odd signatures for event handlers, and just have string literals in... basically it's all a mess. The more clearly you can express your question, the better the chance that we can actually help you.

Comment: Sorry. I think I need to come up with better explanation of what I need. Also looking around Rx ( Reactive extensions ) looks like a good candidate for solution but looks very complex. Thanx so far.

Comment: @john: If you can come up with a clearer description, I'll be happy to take a look. Rx is certainly both complex and awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

Jon's answer is right, this is the equivalent in case it's not convenient to use `delegate`:

```
EventHandler Service1Started()
{
    // Looks like service 1 started as I got event from server class
    server.StartService2();
}
```